# WebGL giving some error

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am trying to figure out the following code. But the problem is that it is giving me an error saying Uncaught Reference error: Detector is not defined. Can some one help me with this. I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I have included all the needed javascript plugins along with this file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="WebGL experiments - Connected Earth experiment">
        <meta name="keywords" content="callum,chrome,collada,earth,example,experiments,globe,google,hurricane tracker,linden,opengl,planet,sample,shader,spline,three.js,webgl,">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="button.css" />
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="Tween.js"></script>
        <script src="planet.js"></script>
        <script src="latlng.js"></script>
        <script src="city_locations.js"></script>
        <script src="Stats.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #000;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
                text-align:left;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #container canvas {
                background: #000;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0px;
            }
            #help {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: 350px;
                height: 400px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -175px;
                margin-top: -200px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 5px solid #666;
                padding: 10px;
                overflow: auto;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            #controls {
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                width:800px;
                height: 38px;
                left: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: -450px;
                background-color: rgba(30, 60, 3, 0.7);
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 5px solid #666;
                padding: 10px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                color: #ff9;
            }
            a {
                color: #9f9;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .hide {
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
                -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
            }
            .show {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
                -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
            }
            img.cornered {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <title>callum.com - Connected Planet</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35129047-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <script>
        var planetTilt = latlngDeg2rad(23.5);
        console.log(planetTilt);
        var planetRadius = 6378;
        var rotationSpeed = 0.3;
        var cloudsScale = 1.02;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer, geometry, meshPlanet, meshClouds;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var cameraZoomFactor = 7;
        var displayHelp = false;
        var curZoom = 100;
        var markerGeom;
        var markerMaterial;
        var stats;

        function onWindowResize(event) {
            width = window.innerWidth;
            height = window.innerHeight;

            renderer.setSize(width, height);

            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            controls.screen.width = width;
            controls.screen.height = height;

            camera.radius = (width + height) / 4;
        }

        function init() {
            if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                clearAlpha: 1,
                clearColor: 0x000000,
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            renderer.sortObjects = true;
            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, width / height, 50, 1e7);
            camera.position.z = planetRadius * cameraZoomFactor;
            scene.add(camera);

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
            controls.noZoom = true;
            controls.noPan = true;
            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.4;

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.right = '0px';

            document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
            dirLight.position.set(1, 0, 1)
                .normalize();
            scene.add(dirLight);
            var camLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            camera.add(camLight);

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            var planet = new cpPlanet({
                planet_radius: planetRadius,
                planet_tilt_rad: planetTilt,
                planet_cloud_texture: "cloud.png",
                planet_surface_texture: "earth_surface.jpg",
                planet_normals_texture: "earth_normals.jpg",
                planet_specular_texture: "earth_specular.jpg",
                planet_geom_segments: 64,
                planet_geom_rings: 64,
                use_surface_shader: true,
                create_combined_mesh: false
            });

            meshPlanet = planet.surface_mesh;
            scene.add(meshPlanet);

            meshClouds = planet.cloud_mesh;
            scene.add(meshClouds);

            // markers and tracks
            var marker_radius = 32;
            var marker_color = 0xff0000;
            markerGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(marker_radius, 5, 5);
            markerMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                ambient: 0x030303,
                color: marker_color,
                specular: 0x990000,
                shininess: 80,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading
            });

            // need to update a bunch of stuff when window size changes
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            var delta = clock.getDelta();

            meshPlanet.rotation.y += rotationSpeed * rotationSpeed * delta;
            meshClouds.rotation.y += rotationSpeed * 1.25 * rotationSpeed * delta;

            controls.update();

            TWEEN.update();

            stats.update();

            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function addData(locs) {

            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * locs.length) - 1;
            var start_lat = locs[index].lat;
            var start_lng = locs[index].lng;

            var data_size = 30;
            var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * locs.length) - 1;
            if (start + data_size > locs.length) {
                start = locs.length - data_size - 1;
            }

            var hue = Math.random();

            var i;
            for (i = start; i < start + data_size; i++) {
                var obj = locs[i];
                if (i != index) {
                    addTrack(start_lat, start_lng, obj.lat, obj.lng, planetRadius, hue);
                    addMarker(obj.lat, obj.lng, planetRadius);
                }
            }
        }

        function zoomToStart() {
            new TWEEN.Tween({
                scale: 1
            })
                .to({
                scale: 100
            }, 2500)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut)
                .onUpdate(function () {
                var true_scale = this.scale / 100;
                meshPlanet.scale.set(true_scale, true_scale, true_scale);
                meshClouds.scale.set(true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale);
            })
                .start();
        }

        function addMarker(lat, lng, radius) {
            var marker_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(markerGeom, markerMaterial);
            var marker_position = latlngPosFromLatLng(lat, lng, radius);

            marker_mesh.position.x = marker_position.x;
            marker_mesh.position.y = marker_position.y;
            marker_mesh.position.z = marker_position.z;

            marker_mesh.name = "trackmarker";
            meshPlanet.add(marker_mesh);
        }

        function addTrackLine(spline, hue) {
            var num_control_points = 32;
            var i;
            var colors = [];
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var pos;

            for (i = 0; i < num_control_points; i++) {
                var index = i / num_control_points;
                pos = spline.getPoint(index);

                colors[i] = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
                colors[i].setHSV(hue, (1.0 - i / num_control_points), 1.0);

                geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
            }
            pos = spline.getPoint(1.0);
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));

            geometry.colors = colors;

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                opacity: 1,
                linewidth: 2
            });
            material.vertexColors = true;

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            line.name = "trackline";
            meshPlanet.add(line);
        }

        function addTrack(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, radius, hue) {
            var num_control_points = 8;
            var max_altitude = 500 + Math.random() * 1200;

            var points = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < num_control_points + 1; i++) {
                var arc_angle = i * 180.0 / num_control_points;
                var arc_radius = radius + (Math.sin(latlngDeg2rad(arc_angle))) * max_altitude;
                var latlng = latlngInterPoint(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, i / num_control_points);
                var pos = latlngPosFromLatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng, arc_radius);

                points.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
            }

            var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);

            addTrackLine(spline, hue);
        }

        function toggleRotation() {
            if (rotationSpeed > 0) rotationSpeed = 0.0;
            else rotationSpeed = 0.3;
        }

        function zoomCamera(zoom_param) {
            var minZoom = 20;
            var maxZoom = 450;
            var incZoom = (maxZoom - minZoom) / 9;
            var timeZoom = 400;
            var startZoom = curZoom;
            var endZoom;

            if (zoom_param == 1) {
                endZoom = curZoom + incZoom;
                if (endZoom > maxZoom) endZoom = maxZoom;
            } else if (zoom_param == -1) {
                endZoom = curZoom - incZoom;
                if (endZoom < minZoom) endZoom = minZoom;
            } else {
                endZoom = zoom_param;
            }

            if (startZoom != endZoom) {
                new TWEEN.Tween({
                    zoom: startZoom
                })
                    .to({
                    zoom: endZoom
                }, timeZoom)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Back.InOut)
                    .onUpdate(function () {
                    curZoom = this.zoom;
                    var true_scale = this.zoom / 100;
                    meshPlanet.scale.set(true_scale, true_scale, true_scale);
                    meshClouds.scale.set(true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale);
                })
                    .onComplete(function () {
                    curZoom = this.zoom;
                })
                    .start();
            }
        }

        function toggleHelp() {
            displayHelp = !displayHelp;
            if (displayHelp) {
                document.getElementById('help')
                    .style.opacity = 1;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('help')
                    .style.opacity = 0;
            }
        }

        function resetView() {
            scene.remove(camera);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, width / height, 50, 1e7);
            camera.position.z = planetRadius * cameraZoomFactor;
            scene.add(camera);

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
            controls.noZoom = true;
            controls.noPan = true;
            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.4;

            zoomCamera(100);
            clock = new THREE.Clock();

            meshPlanet.rotation.y = 0;
            meshClouds.rotation.y = 0;

            rotationSpeed = 0.3
        }

        function addNewData() {
            addData(locations);
        }

        var deleteMe = [];

        function newDataCallback(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Line && node.name == "trackline") {
                deleteMe.push(node);
            }
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh && node.name == "trackmarker") {
                deleteMe.push(node);
            }
        }

        function remAllData() {
            THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy(scene, newDataCallback);

            for (var each = 0; each < deleteMe.length; ++each) {
                meshPlanet.remove(deleteMe[each]);
            }
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            if (!Detector.webgl) {
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                return;
            }

            init();

            var num_new_data_adds = 5;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_new_data_adds; ++i) {
                addData(locations);
            }

            zoomToStart();

            animate();
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="container" class="container"></div>
        <!--<img class="cornered" src="textures/logo.png">-->
        <div id="controls" class="show">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onClick="toggleRotation();" class="button rosy">Rotation</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="zoomCamera(-1);" class="button blue">Zoom Out</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="zoomCamera(+1);" class="button blue">Zoom In</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="addNewData();" class="button green">Add</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="remAllData();" class="button red">Remove All</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="resetView();" class="button pink">Reset</button></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="toggleHelp();" class="button orange">Help</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="help" class="hide">
            <h2>Instructions</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><font color="#da5867">Rotation</font> toggles rotation</li>
                <li><font color="#0095cd">Zoom</font> view in and out</li>
                <li><font color="#64991e">Add</font> random data sets</li>
                <li><font color="#d81b21">Remove</font> all data</li>
                <li><font color="#f895c2">Reset</font> everything</li>
                <li><font color="#f78d1d">Help</font> toggle</li>
            </ul>Contact me at <a href="mailto://callum@gmail.com?subject=WebGL">callum@gmail.com</a>.
            <p>Many thanks to <a href="">Three.js</a>, <a href="">#three.js</a> and the authors of the wealth of example code out there I used to learn from - your generosity is appreciated.<p>
<font color="#699">Version 0.1.0</font>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because detector.js is not loaded. check the paths for your javascript.

```
  <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="Tween.js"></script>
    <script src="planet.js"></script>
    <script src="latlng.js"></script>
    <script src="city_locations.js"></script>
    <script src="Stats.js"></script>
```